# Terminology and the morphology of 'librarian'

Tags: terminology, morphology, derivational-morphology

I was hoping someone could help me out with a terminology question.

What is it called when you remove a letter to add a derivational bound morpheme to a free morpheme (i.e. library + -ian = librar(y)ian.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How to decide whether the final ***/a/*** in ***Oklahoma*** is being retained or "swallowed" when deriving the form ***Oklahoman***?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that depends on the word for the female. ;)

Comment: @Peter: Reduplication. They'd be ***Oklahomamas*** :)